# How to set a background color for the 'tab' character

Tags: terminal, colors, iterm2

I want to apply a background color to tabs in iTerm 2. 
I tried using this:

```
echo -e "\033[42mas\tdf"
```

The above shows "as  df" in Mac Terminal with the entire text colored with green background, but in iTerm 2 only 'as' and 'df' have background color, while the tab whitespace between them is not colored.

Any way to solve this?

Comment: I suggest an edit to the title: "tab characters", not to be confused with the multiple terminal tabs the user interface provides.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried a couple of terminal emulators under Linux, namely its builtin console, xterm, urxvt, vte (gnome-terminal and friends), konsole, terminology (from enlightenment), kitty, pterm (from putty) and st (from suckless). All of them behave as you say iTerm2 does, and unlike Mac's default Terminal.app.

This pretty much suggests that iTerm2 is correct and Terminal.app is the buggy one.

If you have other characters that the TAB skips through, e.g. "er" here:

```
echo -e "qwer\r\033[42mas\tdf"
```

you'll also see that those characters are left untouched and neither replaced by spaces, nor re-colored with a new background. (I've tried it in most emulators I've listed above, not all. Furthermore, I don't have access to a Mac. I'd love to hear what Terminal.app does here.)

This because TAB is not a printable character. It is a cursor moving control character, similarly to other escape sequences.